# PHP: How to Parse JSON From API call?

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a CURL response that looks like this:

```
{"page_number":2,"items":[],"items_per_page":1,"kind":"search#companies","total_results":0,"start_index":1}
```

All i need from that is the value of `"total_results":0`

so I am trying to get `"total_results"` like this:

```
$url = "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q=POOdfgdfgyygfhfgfgfghgfP&items_per_page=1&start_index=0";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "my_password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $output->total_results[0];
```

However, when I echo the `$output->total_results[0];`, I get nothing being echoed on my page. So i don't really know what I am doing wrong!

Could someone please advise on this issue?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver, the data is already decoded on my PHP page. plus, the link you've posted is dead.

Comment: 1. you don't show it and nether did my crystal ball 2. no it's working

Comment: @AbraCadaver, oh, your crystal ball must be broken mate.. lol.. yeah ok pal. cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you got as a response is a JSON string. You can parse it to a `stdClass` object using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$object = json_decode( $output );
```

Then you can access the field you want:

```
$total_results = $object->total_results;
```

Alternatively, you can parse the JSON string to an array:

```
$array = json_decode( $output, true );
```

and get the var:

```
$total_results = $array['total_results'];
```